# function parameter works from an initiated char*, but not if converted from char[]

Tags: c

I have a mqtt function that subscribes to a topic using a char* pointer. Since I want to subscribe only to my own devices id, I need to create part of this pointer dynamicly. And I really cannot manage to succeed.

I have tried to create an array[] dynamicly and then convert the entire array to a pointer array*, with  no success. It only works if I staticly define the pointer in the form char*.

This is what do work well:

```
char* topic="/mqtt_topic/myID/";
mqtt_subscribe(module_inst, topic, 0, SubscribeHandler);
```

The code below compiles and are looking allright, the function is also subscribing to the topic but it does not react on data sent over mqtt. The string is also looking identical with the example above.

```
char topick []="/mqtt_topic/myID/";
char* topic=topick;
mqtt_subscribe(module_inst, topic, 0, SubscribeHandler);
```

The mqtt_subscribe function looks like below;

```
int mqtt_subscribe(struct mqtt_module *module, const char *topic, uint8_t qos, messageHandler msgHandler)
{
    int rc;

    rc = MQTTSubscribe(module->client, topic, qos, msgHandler);
    if(module->callback)
        module->callback(module, MQTT_CALLBACK_SUBSCRIBED, NULL);   

    return rc;
}
```

Which calls the following function.

```
int MQTTSubscribe(MQTTClient* c, const char* topicFilter, enum QoS qos, messageHandler msgHandler)
{ 
    int rc = FAILURE;  
    Timer timer;
    int len = 0;
    MQTTString topic = MQTTString_initializer;
    int Qoss = (int) qos;
    topic.cstring = (char *)topicFilter;
#if defined(MQTT_TASK)
    MutexLock(&c->mutex);
#endif
    if (!c->isconnected)
        goto exit;

    TimerInit(&timer);
    TimerCountdownMS(&timer, c->command_timeout_ms);

    len = MQTTSerialize_subscribe(c->buf, c->buf_size, 0, getNextPacketId(c), 1, &topic, (int*)&Qoss);
 //   len = MQTTSerialize_subscribe(c->buf, c->buf_size, 0, getNextPacketId(c), 1, &topic, qos);
    if (len <= 0)
        goto exit;
    if ((rc = sendPacket(c, len, &timer)) != SUCCESS) // send the subscribe packet
        goto exit;             // there was a problem

    if (waitfor(c, SUBACK, &timer) == SUBACK)      // wait for suback 
    {
        int count = 0, grantedQoS = -1;
        unsigned short mypacketid;
        if (MQTTDeserialize_suback(&mypacketid, 1, &count, &grantedQoS, c->readbuf, c->readbuf_size) == 1)
            rc = grantedQoS; // 0, 1, 2 or 0x80 
        if (rc != 0x80)
        {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < MAX_MESSAGE_HANDLERS; ++i)
            {
                if (c->messageHandlers[i].topicFilter == 0)
                {
                    c->messageHandlers[i].topicFilter = topicFilter;
                    c->messageHandlers[i].fp = msgHandler;
                    rc = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else 
        rc = FAILURE;

exit:
#if defined(MQTT_TASK)
    MutexUnlock(&c->mutex);
#endif
    return rc;
}
```

Is this the expected results? Is there any way of solving this?

Answer (score 5):

You do not show us enough. However, I assume:

```
void myFunction(...)
{
    char topick []="/mqtt_topic/myID/";
    char* topic=topick;
    mqtt_subscribe(module_inst, topic, 0, SubscribeHandler);
    //...
}
```

or something like this, i.e. `topick` is declared inside a function. Then it is a local variable that ceases to exist when the function returns. The pointer to a string you passed does no longer point to a valid string.

On the other hand:

```
char* topic="/mqtt_topic/myID/";
mqtt_subscribe(module_inst, topic, 0, SubscribeHandler);
```

Here `topic` points to a literal and the literal remains to exist after the function returns. So the `mqtt_..` function receives a valid string that also exists after the caller returns.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is completely correct and I am indeed declaring the array locally. Declaring the `topick[64]` globally solved this issue.

Thanks!

/Mikael